# Not oxymoron or paradox

Tags: meaning

What do you call one word that is contradictory? It is not an oxymoron or a paradox. I can never remember the term!

Comment: Are you thinking of *irony?*

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "one word that is contradictory"? Or give some examples?

Answer (score 2):

A [contranym](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/fun/wordplay/autoanto.html), also known as *autoantonym* or "Janus word" (after the two-headed Roman god) is a word or phrase which "contradicts itself"; that is, has two distinct meanings which are opposite.

Examples include *fast*: (moving quickly or constrained from moving), *cleave* (to cut apart or to cling together), *left* (remaining or departed), *oversight* (watching out for errors or failing to see an error), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of [heterological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)?

> An autological word (also called homological word) is a word that expresses a property that it also possesses (e.g. the word "short" is short, "noun" is a noun, "English" is English, "pentasyllabic" has five syllables, "word" is a word, "sesquipedalian" is a long word; see Wiktionary for a partial list). The opposite is a heterological word, one that does not apply to itself (e.g. "long" is not long, "verb" is not typically a verb, "phonetic" is not spelled the way it sounds, "monosyllabic" has five syllables, "German" is not German, etc.).

Comment: Heterological makes me think of the notion of arbitrariness; I don't see any contradiction in the examples you provided.

Comment: *Monosyllabic* isn't monosyllabic; *verb* is not a verb; and so on.  They are in that sense self-contradictory.

Comment: Like most words - fat is not fat; big is not big; emaciated  is not emaciated etc. that's why I thought of arbitrariness.

Comment: No word is "fat"!  Many words are verbs, just not *verb*; many words are German, but *German* is French; *monosyllabic* is long but not monosyllabic while *long* is monosyllabic but not long.  Does that make it seem less arbitrary?